# How to provide relative url/ftp url while linking an excel file to Access db in a ftp file server?

Tags: excel, ms-access

I'm currently working on a legacy .asp site which uses a .mdb file as the database. Both .asp file and mdb file are stored in the server.
The mdb file and contents of the tables are managed by a third party. Recently they have tried to link an excel file to this access db using Linked table manager.

Since they have linked it from their local system, the path/Data source information is the path in their local system. Hence I'm getting an error while reading from the linked excel table via the mdb.

My aim is to correctly link the excel file (Which has also been uploaded to file server to the same folder) to access db so that I can use it with the VB asp site.

I have added the ftp server in my system and when I try to select that location, It gives me the following error

[Error-message: You cannot use an Internet address here. Enter a path that points to a location on your computer or on the network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dE3m.png)

Comment: What is "that location"? What's needed is most likely a mapped drive or a UNC path.

Comment: Sorry if my question wasn't clear. "That location" is a server where the mdb file and excel file is stored. I connect it to using an ftp connection string. I don't have any other credential to access it. 

I tried mapping it as a network drive, but it doesn't support ftp connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you don't mention how it is possbile you are able to open + use the mdb file that is sitting on a web site? do you have direct use of the folders and files on YOUR network that also includes the mdb file?

They can link to a excel file, but it MUST BE part of the folder structure on the web site, and you can't link to a ftp file in access - you never could.

So, if that folder where the excel file is PART OF the same network AND PART of the windows folders being used, then fine. However, you can't link to a web site, or ftp from access, and you never could.

So, if there is a direct plane jane windows path name to the Excel file, then that can be linked. But, using FTP is out of the question.

So, if you now have some folders on that web server that you able to see/use/read/play with now, and that includes the mdb file? (and again, NOT ftp, but direct opening of the mdb file), then again, that Excel file can be linked in the access mdb file. On the other hand, since you have direct use of the mdb file, then you very likely have direct use of the Excel file. But in ANY and ALL cases, any file operations used with a mdb file are to be full 100% plane jane windows path names - not http, and not FTP.

As noted, you not explained how you are able to use that mdb file that is stitting behind a web server. And as noted, it is possble the web server and MORE important the files for the web server are on your same network. but, if you using the mdb file by FTP, then you dowloading a WHOLE file local, and then opening the mdb file, and hence you have zero connection to the web server and files in that case.

So, the big elephant, the big whopper, the big issue? You left out how you are able to use that mdb file that is sitting behind the web server. In fact, as a general rule, it is not possible for you to see/use/get use of the mdb file, so this issue needs to be explained how this is possible, since it as a general rule is not possible.

However, as noted, if the web server folder and files are on YOUR network now? Then any Excel file linked ALSO has to be on that SAME network - and ftp does not count.

So, if a direct file path link to the Excel file is being used, and the folder/server where the Excel files exist is PART OF the SAME network, then you can directly link to the Excel file. However, linking via ftp, or http is not possible - Access is a desktop file based system, and it can ONLY EVER work with direct path names for linked file operations. So, any file, any link has to be a plane jane direct file path, and one that is part of the network.

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks for the detailed reply.
The files are stored in a web server which I access using an ftp connection string. I downloaded the excel file and .MDB file to my system using that to test locally. 

I couldn't map it as a network drive from my system since it's a ftp it's not possible. 
Thanks again. I'll try using a different approach.